# android apps using google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

can we display all this three Criteria grocery store,pet store,mobile store of one particular area in google map

goto this link http://maps.google.co.in/ then type California,grocery store then erase grocery store and type California,walmart...i want to combine those two google maps

Comment: for eg: i need to display grocery stores,pet stores and mobile store of california in one map...

Answer (score 1):

First, look at getting started with a map activity:

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/01/01/android/getting-started-with-android-map-view/

Then look into how to query using the geocoder:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/gecoding-example/

Then you'll just combine them for your particular uses.

But yes, what you're looking for is possible.

Comment: hi u have not got my question...first thing we goto some particular area in google map for eg califonia in tat area map i need grocery stores,pet stores and walmart of califonia(all the three stores should be displayed on google map)

Comment: Hi... yes I did.

If you understood the map activity (MapView link) you would realize that there are options like "animateTo" or "zoomToSpan" that will take you to those areas. If you understood the geocoder service, you would understand that using the API you can pass searches to google maps and get results back... search data like "pet store", or "grocery store". I understood your question... please take the time to learn... no one is going to write your app for you.

Comment: will it display all the three criterias in one map...all the grocery stores,pet stores and mobile stores of califonia in one map